# Is there any way to find pid for eventmachine's popen?

Tags: eventmachine

In ruby standard library, popen return a object which has pid method,
In eventmachine, popen return a Connection object which contain no process id information.

Demo code here:

```
require 'eventmachine'

def work
  s = EM.popen('ls')
  puts s.pid # how to get new process's pid?
end

EventMachine.run {
  work
  EM.stop
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EM.popen returns a standard a EM Connection object, you can use `s.get_pid` to get the pid of the subprocess.

http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Connection.html#get_pid-instance_method